# LEFT JOIN 2 columns within the same table if the same value is available in both column

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-server-2012, left-join

I have this table. What I want to achieve is a `LEFT JOIN` to only work if 2 values within the same column is present.

For example, `LEFT JOIN` will only work on `EA-AC-A060047` since it's both available for credit and debit columns. And so on.

[image: pic1]

This is what I'm trying to achieve.

[image: pic2]

This is what I got so far, no luck.

```
SELECT 
    t1.referenceno, t2.credit, t3.debit 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         referenceno, credit, debit, employeeidno 
     FROM
         earningsamendment 
     WHERE 
         employeeidno = 'D0080000010') AS t1
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
         referenceno, credit, debit, employeeidno 
     FROM
         earningsamendment 
     WHERE
         employeeidno = 'D0080000010') AS t2 ON t2.referenceno = t1.referenceno
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
         referenceno, credit, debit, employeeidno 
     FROM
         earningsamendment 
     WHERE
         employeeidno = 'D0080000010') AS t3 ON t3.referenceno = t1.referenceno
WHERE
    t2.referenceno = t1.referenceno 
    AND t3.referenceno = t1.referenceno
ORDER BY  
    t1.referenceno
```

Comment: For the last value on credit is available. But you are saying - * both available for credit and debit columns*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily achieve this by using `group by` and 'max`, if you have only 1 row each for credit and debit column.

```
   select referenceno, max(credit) as Credit, max(debit) as Debit , employeeidno 
   from earningsamendment group by referenceno, employeeidno
```

This above query give the result as expected posted in above question.

Now if you want to get the record only if both `credit` and `debit` is present.

```
   ; with cte as (
   select referenceno, max(credit) as Credit, max(debit) as Debit , employeeidno 
   from earningsamendment group by referenceno, employeeidno 
   )
   select * from cte where Credit>0 and Debit>0
```

Comment: That will skip the value with the *referenceno* that does not have a pair in debit/credit.  ex. *EA-HR-A061393* will not show on the query.

Comment: no, this will give the exact result what do you want. @pjustindaryll: at least test this before marking any comment. If there is any situation in which this will not work then kindly post that scenario with input and expected output.

Comment: Apologies, I edited my database previously, that's why I'm getting different results. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a left join to only work when two values are present - ie you want it to not return anything if not the case, it sounds like an inner join. So start with distinct reference numbers/employee numbers. The assumption is that there will not be more than one credit and not more than one debit...

SELECT * from

( SELECT DISTINCT
   referenceno,
   employeeidno
 from
earningsamendment) as t1

INNER JOIN

(   SELECT referenceno,employeeidno,

```
  (SELECT credit from earningsamendment e3
     where e3.employeeidno = e2.employeeidno and
           e3.referenceno = e2.referenceno and
           isnull(e3.credit ,0) <> 0  ) as credit,


  (SELECT debit from earningsamendment e3
     where e3.employeeidno = e2.employeeidno and
           e3.referenceno = e2.referenceno and
           isnull(e3.debit ,0) <> 0  ) as debit
  FROM earningsamendment e2
  GROUP BY referenceno,employeeidno
```

) as t2

ON t2.referenceno=t1.referenceno and t2.employeeidno = t1.employeeidno

WHERE NOT t2.debit IS NULL AND NOT t2.credit IS NULL

Comment: This is another way to do it. I'll study this one. Thank you.